# Analyzer Option or Lint Option for Flutter private variables?

Tags: flutter, dart, variables, private

I am building a very large codebase and spending many hours at a time on it. This can lead to me often forgetting to make a variable private, that could be private. There is currently no Analyzer warning, nor no Lint warning informing me that such variable could be private. This is a common warning when working with Java in Android Studio and it's often appreciated to tighten up a Class and make the code more readable.

Thus, is there a similar Analyzer Option or Lint Option which can be enabled to warn when a variables access could be tightened up?

Thank you

- Create an unnecessarily public variable
  Expectation: warning
  Result: no warning

Comment: How do you expect the analyzer to know whether a variable is intended to be part of your package's public API?

Comment: @jamesdlin if there's no public usage of the variable then the suggestion to make it private should be offered. Same as in Java analysis.

Comment: I don't use Java.  How do you determine public usage?  It's common for a library to provide APIs that it might not internally use (and that wouldn't necessarily be "public usage" anyway).  Is your expectation that analysis would rely on all public APIs being referenced in tests?

Comment: @jamesdlin determining public usage within your codebase is what I meant. I suppose if Dart is assuming all files are libraries for external consumption then yes I get your point. None of my files are consumed outside of my codebase, so I wish it was possible to point out which variables could be private easily.